# How to fetch Gmail on PHP IMAP?

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I try this hosts:

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}Current Batch
{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}
{imap.gmail.com:995/ssl/serivce=pop3}INBOX
```

None of them worked. What is Gmail host or what IMAP settings?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked that port 993 isn't firewalled off on your host?

Answer (score 3):

The imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX should be the right one. How are you using this in your php code? Do you just want to receive your email? Because than it will look something like this:

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'youremail@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Comment: My code is:

<?php 
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'email@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$num_msgs = imap_num_msg($inbox);
imap_close($inbox);
echo $num_msgs;
?>

Answer: Connection timed out.

Comment: Does it help if you close the connection after you echo $num_msgs?

Comment: Does not get to the point. 
The $inbox line for PHP exiting connection timed out.
Will not print $num_msgs.

Comment: If you get error like "Please log in via your web browser: " try 2 setp verifcation and app specific password as answered by abhishek gupta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377560/please-log-in-via-your-web-browser-https-support-google-com-mail-accounts-ans

Comment: Man! You saved a poor soul.

Answer (score 0):

Setting are as follows:

```
$mail = new Imap([
      'host'  => 'imap.gmail.com',
      'user'  => 'username@gmail.com',
      'password' => 'password',
      'port'  => 993,
      'ssl'   => 'SSL',
]);
```

Then go to https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps and check 'Allow less secure apps'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code example which connects and fetches emails from gmail :

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'gmail_email_address';
$password = 'password';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {        
        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';        
        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);        
        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {                
                /* get information specific to this email */
                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
                $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);                
                /* output the email header information */
                $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
                $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
                $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
                $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
                $output.= '</div>';

                /* output the email body */
                $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
        }        
        echo $output;
}
imap_close($inbox);
```

- Enter correct email id and password.
- You might wanna replace

  $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

with something like this to narrow the results

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SINCE "19 October 2018"');
```

or you might get a timeout error.

- You might have to enable 2 step verification on google account and use app specific passowrd if you get error like [Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377560/please-log-in-via-your-web-browser-https-support-google-com-mail-accounts-ans)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with PHP IMAP and connecting to gmail.

First make sure you have enabled IMAP in your gmail settings (default is off!).

Second SSL IMAP on PHP has problems with several versions.

To get it to work choose : {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}

Go into your Google Account (not gmail this time), go to security and allow access from less secure methods (Allow less secure apps).

Then it works.
Hopefully there will be a fix one day