# Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to my mail box using the java mail api based on imap protocol. I check and for sure I inserting the correct parameters. This is the following exception that I got:

> [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)

I do not know why it is happens in addition I enabled the imap option in my gmail account settings.

Ihis is my code:

```
 Properties protocol = new Properties();
 protocol.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

 try{
      Session session = Session.getInstance(protocol, null);
      Store store = session.getStore();
      String host = prop.getProperty("host");
      String email = prop.getProperty("username");
      String password = prop.getProperty("password");
      store.connect(host, email, password);
      Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
      int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
      model.addAttribute("msg","number of mails"+" "+messageCount);
      Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(username+".txt", "UTF-8");

      for(int i=0;i<messageCount || prop.getProperty("status").equals(status.RUNNING.toString()) ;i++ ){
          model.addAttribute("msg","Reading Mails");
          Multipart mp = (Multipart) messages[i].getContent();
          BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
          writer.println("From:"+ messages[i].getFrom()+" "+"Subject:"+messages[i].getSubject()+" "+"Message:"+bp.getContent());
          prop =  loadProperties(username+".properties");
       }
       writer.close();
       inbox.close(true);
       store.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
                    model.addAttribute("msg","Exception:"+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Did you activate `IMAP` protocoll in your gmail account? It's not open per default, you need to dig in to the settings and enable it https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en

Comment: yes the imap is enabled as i said above.

Comment: does the host of gmail should be imap.gmail.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching I found that I need to change the host name to `imap.googlemail.com`

the following code was changed:

```
mail.store.protocol
```

changed to:

```
imap.googlemail.com
```

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you doing the following:

1. Just enable [2-step verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) on your account.
2. Then generate one [App-Specific-Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and us that to connect instead of your original password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case google detected change in usual pattern of login and needs a verification.

As indicated by response message we will need to login using web browser(from the machine where the IMAP client is running). We will be asked for verification then(I added a recovery email which provides one method of verification) and after verifying I was able to login using the IMAP client.